# Get a Windows7 printer driver w/o Internet connection

Tags: windows-7, printing

I will go on a site where is a HP PSC 1350 printer but no internet connection. I understand that there is no driver for download available from HP and it will connect to WinUpdate once connected the printer with USB. But there will be no Internet. Any chance to get the driver without connection to the printer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the message.

Yes, it says *Install the Driver Using Windows Update with a USB Connection (Downloadable Driver Not Available)*, but if you click that link, it leads you to [this page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01796879&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4062&product=306888&sw_lang=). That page indicates that there are no drivers for Windows 7 available for download because they are already included in Windows 7’s driver cache. It only goes online to check if a *newer* driver is available (which is unlikely, otherwise they would have made it available for download). If there is no Internet connection, then it just installs the driver it has.

So when you arrive at on site, just plug the printer into the Windows 7 machine and it will automatically install the appropriate drivers, Internet connection or no.

As a backup plan / confirmation, what you can do if possible, is to connect the printer to another machine that *does* have an Internet connection. If it just installs the driver, then you know you’re good to go on the other machine. If it has to download the driver, then after it is finished, you can copy the self-extracting archive containing the driver from `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` (you may have to do some searching to find the right one, so you may want to temporarily move all the files in there to somewhere else before plugging in the printer).

Comment: And if all else fails, go through the options to manually select a driver and use the HP Universal one.

Comment: What would be the point to that? The universal driver (which in my experience is iffy at best) would still depend on the built-in driver cache of Windows 7, in which case you may as well just use the correct one.

Comment: @Synetech, I did this some time before and Win7 installs a driver for another model and won't work :-( I hope with Win7 updated right now it will work.

Comment: Try removing the printer completely. Open Device Manager (devmgmt.msc), select *View->Show hidden devices*, expand the printers branch, right-click the printer and select Uninstall. (Consider rebooting for good measure.) Then plug the printer in and let it detect and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you download the driver from HP and put it on a CD-ROM or usb stick?

[hp link to download driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?product=306888&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&cc=us)

Comment: Had you followed through on the page you liked to, and selected Windows-7 (per the question tag) from the drop-down, you would have observed that it says **Install the Driver Using Windows Update with a USB Connection (Downloadable Driver Not Available)**, as Peter said in the question.

Comment: I only tried for win XP (the version I have installed) and there is a driver to download but if HP says the driver is already inside win7 and works for printing, faxing and scanning... well, this is good news and I think the problem is solved. The OP won't need to do anything to use the printer (only plugging it in the USB).

Comment: The question is tagged `Windows-7`. (Sometimes I overlook the tags too.)

Answer (score 0):

Contact HP to see what options they may have in this situation. They may be able to get you a physical disk, possibly for a small handling fee.

Comment: That won’t work because the drivers are already included in Windows 7.